# Get sum() result in one query in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table

```
id name state num
1  x    in    10
2  x    out   1
3  x    in    5
4  x    out   2
5  y    ...
6  y    ...
```

The expected result is to sum the num for 'in' and 'out' in one query and then calculate the difference, like

```
name numin numout diff
x    15    3      12
y    ....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `GROUP BY` (and the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement):

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN state='in' THEN num ELSE 0 END CASE) AS numin,
  SUM(CASE WHEN state='out' THEN num ELSE 0 END CASE) AS numout,
  SUM(CASE WHEN state='in' THEN num ELSE -1*num END CASE) AS diff
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  name
```